# Is it possible to if ..else staement under subscribe() angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, if-statement, frontend

M working with spring boot as backend and angular. I got two error response from backend. 'Unauthorized' and 'Please verify email' I want to know is it possible to check condition as given code below.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the usage of the condition inside the `error` callback. However why would you force reload the page after 1 second upon a successful login? And why do have two separate booleans for denoting the login status? You could just use `isLoggedIn` and set it to false in the error callback. Also please don't post code as image.

Comment: You have already check it, so what is the problem?

Comment: Its my first post so m unware of that so i have  posted code as image. Thank for your response.

Comment: side note: the use of `setTimeout` is troubling. What purpose does that serve?

Comment: `Its my first post so m unware of that so i have posted code as image.` ← That is OK as long as you please [edit] your question and add the code you have shown in your image and then remove the image.

Comment: @RohitChaudhary, a response from a service fall in "error" (1) if there're an error (e.g. you has no access to your APIor there an error in API). You say that the response can be 'Unauthorized' and 'Please verify email'. You need check the response in subscribe, not in error: `subscribe(data=>{..here check the response..}`. (1) well, really in your service is possible throw an exception, but I think that it's not your case

Comment: @Shifenis  its not working. I got 'Unauthorized' response from backend but it execute else statement. May be i have made error on if condition so i wanna know is it correct?

Comment: @Igor I will note that. Thank u

Comment: _"I got 'Unauthorized' response from backend but it execute else statement"_ - do a `console.log(err)` inside the error callback and post the output as screenshot here. Most probably the error message is defined elsewhere and not in `err.error.message`.

Comment: @Michael D thank you. Its silly mistakes. I got it. I have not written complete response message in if statement. if(this.errorMessage=='Error: Unauthorized')